# Как реализовать 2 перменные SET @var = value в одном исходе выражения IF?

Tags: sql, set

Таблица для обновления выглядит так, в общих чертах:

```
Event_id - city_id - event_day
```

Хочу формировать накопление кол-ва (порядковых) дней в поле event_day. Если city_id не меняется, то прибавляю 1 (день), если меняется, то прибавляю 3 (дня). Практически, если событие в том же городе, то расходуется 1 день, а если в другом, то тратится 3 дня с учетом переезда.

```
    SET @day = 0;
    SET @num_id = 1;
    
    UPDATE event 
    SET 
    event_day = 
    IF(city_id = @num_id,
       (@day := @day + 1),
       (@day := @day + 3) AND (@num_id := @num_id + 1))
    ;
```

```
SELECT city_id, event_day FROM event;
```

Получаю почти ожидаемый результат, но в строках, где event_id = 4 и 7, появляется значение 1 вместо 6 и 11, соответственно.

```
+----------+---------+-----------+
| event_id | city_id | event_day |
+----------+---------+-----------+
| 1        | 1       | 1         |
| 2        | 1       | 2         |
| 3        | 1       | 3         |
| 4        | 2       | 1         |
| 5        | 2       | 7         |
| 6        | 2       | 8         |
| 7        | 3       | 1         |
| 8        | 3       | 12        |
| 9        | 3       | 13        |
+----------+---------+-----------+
```

Выглядит как результат True после логической операции. Непонятно, как правильно добавить `(@num_id := @num_id + 1)` в запрос с IF. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Предварительный рабочий код

1. Создание таблицы:

```
    CREATE TABLE event(
        event_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        city_id INT,
        city VARCHAR(30),
        genre VARCHAR(30),
        author VARCHAR(30),
        title VARCHAR(30),
        event_day INT,
        num_id INT
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить задачу через дополнительное поле.

```
UPDATE event 
SET 
event_day = 
IF(city_id = @num_id,
   @day := @day + 1,
   @day := @day + 3),
num_id = 
IF(city_id = @num_id,
   @num_id,
   @num_id := @num_id + 1)
;
```

Можно ли решать задачу прямо, без дополнительного поля?